Powerbi Custom visual Filter Api - cross filtering
I am creating a custom visual where I need to know on which field I am getting filtered data.
for eg: let say I have my visual containing 3 fields now there is another slicer (powerbi slicer) visual which contain one of the three fields. Now if the filter has been applied from powerbi-slicer, how can I identify on which field filter has been applied?
Currently What I am doing is saving initial load whole data and on each rendering I am checking if there is filter happening or not (by dataViews metadata properties "isDataFilterApplied") if there is filteration then I am comparing for any differences but this is also not working in some cases.
Please Help, Thanks
